# C# How can I control the output pins of an USB LPT cable

Tags: usb, lpt

I have an USB LPT cable [(Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0H1q.jpg) and I want to control its output pins.
I am not familiar with USB connection coding. I searched, but I can't find anything useful for USB LPT coding.

Can anyone share simple code for controlling the output pins.

Comment: I improved highlighting and some grammar. Also copied the image to stack.imgur.com.

Answer (score 0):

There are many code examples for this kind of scenario. You didn't mention your OS, so I assume a flavor of Windows, but for Linux it's similar.

Look at the [great site CodeProject](https://www.google.de/search?q=site:codeproject.com+USB+LPT) for Windows sample code and adjust it to your needs.